# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Arrows not toggling on the result list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an autocomplete that's almost working as I want it to work. The problem that I have is that once I start searching for my items and I get a few suggestions, I would then like to use my arrows to click through the different suggestions. It toggles the different suggestions in the input field itself, but it doesnt move on to the list and "toggle" through them.

This is my code

```
function () {
    $("#geosearch").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: cities,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            addLocation(ui.item);
            return false;
        }

    });          
}
```

What do I need to add to make it work? The funny thing is that all examples I find, have a working "arrow browsing" but my just wont do it :(

Comment: Can you set up an example on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) showing the problem?

Comment: it works well on jsfiddle. Problem is EPiServer and all its crappy JS that's stopping it from working :(

Answer (score 0):

If by arrow browsing you are referring to traversing through the suggestion list using your keyboard's arrow keys, then I think your focus method is the one where the action will take place.

Is there any particular reason why you added the "event.preventDefault();" in the focus event? It may be cancelling out the focus event from getting raised properly and notifying jqueryui to move the highlight on the selected item to the next/prev one.

Comment: if I take away event.preventDefault(), then the keys will instead toggle between value and label, which makes an awful result :) And yes, I ment traversing through the suggestion list. My english is simply not enough sometimes :)

Comment: So you have a list of cities which when you traverse using the arrow keys, you want the city that is currently "focused" to be shown on the #geosearch input field right? Assuming #geosearch is a textbox. This behaviour should already be working without much customizations.

Comment: I'm trying your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSckL/) and it seems to be working.

Comment: thanx snasirca. I have a huge problem though, and that's that this is a plugin for EPiServer (a cms) and there might be some other javascript there that might be interfering. Because as you said, that should work out of the box but it isnt. So my guess is that's something blocking it. It's an old version of episerver too so it only works on IE. It just crashes on FF and Chrome so I can't really debug that well besides on IE.

Answer (score 0):

The autosuggestion css class of the list is

```
.ui-corner-all
```

and when its highlighted it becomes

```
.ui-state-focus
```

If you write a style for it then the issue would get solved. For eg:

```
.ui-state-focus {
 background:#F00; 
}
```